# Google sheets - linking value from another sheet using LOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Expected result (formula cells being **bold**):

| SHEET 1 |  | SHEET 2 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key | Expected value | Key | Misc data | Expected value |
| 12 | **C** | 10 | asd | A |
| 14 | **E** | 11 | asd | B |
| 10 | **A** | 12 | asd | C |
|  |  | 13 | asd | D |
|  |  | 14 | asd | E |

The formula I'm trying to use is

```
=LOOKUP(A2,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A,'Sheet2'!$C$2:$C)
```

When I use this on a single sheet (tab) then it works as intended. However as soon as I'm trying to get data from another sheet, it fails with:

Error
Did not find value 'KEY' in LOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: According to your table, isn't your key value in: 'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A ?

Comment: I used the actual formula from my document, I updated the formula to fit the example, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the key columns holding values with different data types (number vs plain text). After setting both to same data type, the formula started working.